# Custom Bean Sugarcrm

Tags: javabeans, sugarcrm

Apologize for my English. With sugarCRM when I create my own module by using module builder
, the module type that I found are Basic, Company, File, Issue, Person and Sale.
If I want to create another module like "The Patient" that has more properties than Person type (eg., Patient ID, Blood Pressure, Precaution status, Chronic disease and some drug allergy information) How can I create it from scratch.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the listed module types (all except Basic) can be considered templates, and the advantage of using them is that they come ready-made with common relevant fields. It does sound as though your "Patient" module will benefit from starting with the Person template. From there, you can add as many extra fields as you want.

An example of when you would want to choose Basic, on the other hand, is when you want to start with the bare minimum (as determined by the SugarCRM architecture), and you don't want to have to deal with a lot of extraneous default fields that won't ever be used, and can't be deleted. The custom modules I have built often have nothing to do with conventional CRM needs, and therefore none of the other templates have any relevant fields.

In your case, I would go ahead and start with the Person template. Take a look at the default fields that Module Builder gives you to start with. If there are more than a few that you wouldn't use (and would always be cluttering up the Patient module), then consider starting with the Basic template instead.